# No quotef for first value in csv

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv

I am trying to make a very simple CSV file, everything works except one tiny thing : when the file get opened in Excel, the very first value of each entry isn't quoted, e.g :

```
username,"fullname","fullname@company.com"
```

And here is the code :

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

// Get user info
foreach (User u in listUsers)
{
    sb.AppendFormat("\"{0}\",\"{1}\",\"{2}\"\r\n", u.Username, u.Fullname, u.EMail);
}

// Generate csv
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + "UsersExport.csv" + "\"");
Response.Write(sb.ToString());
Response.End();
```

Any idea?

Comment: hmmm interesting ... seems like a dumb thing to ask but ... have you checked the actual csv output is in quotes for all fields?

Comment: I agree with Wardy, the code looks fine - it may just be excel; it can be a pain if you don't pick the right column types when importing CSV files. Oh and might I suggest you use a TAB seperate file (TSV) instead, much more reliable if you have fields that may contain commas

Comment: Open the file in note pad and compare the field with other fields. If there is any difference that might be the cause for the problem.

Comment: Thank you all, indeed once opened the .csv with Notepad or exported as plain text, the quotes are present. Also when I export a file.csv and open it from Excel (tab Data / From text) chosing the format of csv I want, there is works as well.
However, with the present code, by default, the dialog box proposes to open the file with Excel and there it doesn't work ... I wonder whether there is a solution to this ...

Comment: I have seen somehting like this before when not applying a header record, try inserting an empty row at the start of the file just to test something like ",,\r\n" ... if that makes a difference the bug is in excel if it doesn't i'm a little lost.

Comment: Out of curiosity what is excel showing? ...

Comment: Unfortunately the empty row didn't do the trick. Here is a screenshot of the Excel output : http://hpics.li/3345be0